# What is async* and what does yield keyword in Flutter? does yield keyword add type stream to the returned value?

Tags: list, flutter, stream

```
class ChatsController {
  static const String CHATS="chats", RECENT="recent", MESSAGES="messages";

  static Stream<List<Chat>> getChats() async* {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore=FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    Usern user= await UserController.getUser();
    List<Usern> activeUsers= await UserController.getActiveUsers();
    await for(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snap in firestore.collection(RECENT).doc(user.id).collection("history").snapshots()){
  try {
 List<Chat> chats=snap.docs.map((doc)=>Chat.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>.from(doc.data()))).toList();
 chats.forEach((chat) {
   chat.to.isActive=false;
   chat.from.isActive=false;
   if(chat.to.id!=user.id) {
     activeUsers.forEach((temp) {
       if(temp.id==chat.to.id) {
         chat.to.isActive=true;
       }

     });
   }
   else {
     activeUsers.forEach((temp) {
       if(temp.id== chat.from.id) {
         chat.from.isActive= true;
       }

     });
   }
  });
  yield chats;
  
}catch(e){

  }

   }
  }
}

In this example if I have used return keyword instead of yield , what would have 
happened? Would it complain that I am returning List<Chat> instead of 
Stream<List<Chat>. Does yield keyword adds stream to the List<Chat> I am trying to 
return in the end....likewise async* keyword, does it mean that this function has
```

future type return associated with it? I mean to say that can I say that this function
returns the Stream<List> just because it has stream snapshot used inside code
eventhough I actually only returned "List>"?

Answer (score 0):

An `async*` is "asynchronous generator function", which must always return `Stream<T>` and `yield` is used `add` a value into the stream. You cannot used the `return` keyword inside a `async*` function.

Read about that in the [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generators)